# PostMessage WM_KEYDOWN while holding CTRL?

Tags: c++, winapi, postmessage

If i be holding the `CTRL` key down while sending a `PostMessage` containing `WM_KEYDOWN` it 'mess' with the message.

I couldn't understand what really happens, if it sends `CTRL` plus the message being sent or what?

How to reproduce:

Launch `notepad` and hold the `CTRL` key while the code is running

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

struct extraKeyInfo
{
    unsigned short repeatCount;
    unsigned char scanCode;
    bool extendedKey, prevKeyState, transitionState;

    operator unsigned int()
    {
        return repeatCount | (scanCode << 16) | (extendedKey << 24) |
            (prevKeyState << 30) | (transitionState << 31);
    }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    auto hwnd = FindWindow(0, L"Untitled - Notepad");
    HWND hEdit = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, TEXT("Edit"), NULL);

    for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) // Output a-z in Notepad
    {
        short vkCode = LOBYTE(VkKeyScan(ch));

        extraKeyInfo lParam = {};
        lParam.scanCode = MapVirtualKey(vkCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

        PostMessage(hEdit, WM_KEYDOWN, vkCode, lParam);

        lParam.repeatCount = 1;
        lParam.prevKeyState = true;
        lParam.transitionState = true;

        PostMessage(hEdit, WM_KEYUP, vkCode, lParam);
        Sleep(200);
    }

}
```

Is possible somehow to send just the desired key into the `PostMessage` independent if i have any keydown?

Comment: Try sending `WM_CHAR` instead. Apparently, you want Notepad to process a particular character, not a particular keypress.

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513)

Comment: This is a perfect example of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Your proposed solution won't solve your problem. What's the *specific* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik do you mean sending just `WM_CHAR` instead of `WM_KEYDOWN`? or `WM_CHAR` after the `WM_KEYDOWN`? i dont understand

Comment: @Louis yes, `WM_CHAR` *instead of* `WM_KEY(DOWN|UP)`. But really, what exactly are you trying to achieve in the first place? That is the `X` in the `XY Problem`. Using `WM_CHAR`/`WM_KEY...` is the `Y`, so what is the `X` you are trying to solve?

Comment: @RemyLebeau the 'problem' i'm trying to solve, is send just the desired key to the window, even when i have any key physically down, as described if i hold down `LCTRL` and use the script above it doesn't send `a,b,c,d,e[...]` it send `ctrl+a`, `ctrl+b` [...]

Comment: Incorrect. You are not *sending* the Ctrl state at all. That would require you to set your `extendedKey` value, which you are not doing. What makes you think the receiving window is not simply querying the current Ctrl state, ie via `Get(Async)KeyState()`, regardless of whatever you send?

Comment: @RemyLebeau and sending it as `WM_CHAR` it will not "merge" the received key with the current Ctrl state?

Comment: No. When the receiving window's message queue processes `WM_KEY...` messages, it generates `WM_CHAR` messages accordingly. So, if you send `WM_CHAR` yourself, there is nothing to "merge".

Comment: @RemyLebeau wow i didnt know about this, could you provide an example using WM_CHAR i think it would be enough to be marked as an answer

Comment: "*wow i didnt know about this*" - That is what happens when you don't do your research first. For instance, read [About Keyboard Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input) on MSDN. "*could you provide an example using WM_CHAR*" - `PostMessage(hEdit, WM_CHAR, ch, lParam);` But I agree with IInspectable, this sounds like an `XY Problem`, and you should not be sending keys in this manner to begin with (as I [already commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72624305/?noredirect=1#comment128287366_72624305) earlier).